# If I looped + and - terminals of a single AA 1.5 V, 2 Ah battery with a broad wire

Tags: batteries, current, wire

If I looped + and - terminals of a single AA 1.5 V, 2 Ah battery with 1 meters of AWG 000 wire (2/10^4 ohms/meter),would there be a current of

V = IR,   I = 1.5*(10^4)/2 = 7500 Amps ?

If so, then would the battery die in 2*3600/7500 = 0.96 seconds and form such a strong magnetic field briefly?

If not, what prevents this from happening?

Answer (score 6):

You'll never get such a high current from an alkaline/ni-mh battery because the internal resistance will be too high (0.1 - 1ohm, possible even more). You can usually short such a battery for a brief period and it should not cause damage, although I wouldn't advise it in any case since the wire will get very hot and you may end up burning yourself.

Battery resistance may vary from manufacturer to manufacturer, but a rough guide can be found here: 
http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Battery-internal-resistance

Answer (score 3):

The internal resistance of the battery is significant and makes the current much lower. For a AA battery, it is usually greater than 0.1 Ohm. So it would make a current of 15 Amps only (still big, though). There is no way you could get 7500 Amps from such a battery, even for a short time.

Here is an [interesting article](http://data.energizer.com/PDFs/BatteryIR.pdf) about batteries internal resistance.